# Delphi 7 Сокеты

Tags: delphi-7, сокеты

Как в Delphi 7 можно передать файл через сокеты, облазил весь интернет, конкретной темы не нашел и мне кажется что каждый сайт у друг друга идеи на счет этого крадут :)

Желательно исходник.

Пробовал передавать через TMemoryStream, ибо не могу понять как там принять "Stream"...

Comment: Нужно использовать TFileStream на сервере, а еще лучше, чтобы вы, также показывали скрипты, что уже делали, что не получилось и т. д. А то - телепаты в отпуске.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передать-то не велика проблема. Я предпочитаю хардкор, то есть работать с "сырыми" массивами байт. То есть читаем файл в динамический массив байт, к сожалению в Delphi 7 нет функции чтобы сделать это быстро, но можно написать самостоятельно, я вот так сделал:

```
type
  TByteArray = array of byte;

function FileReadAllBytes(fileName: string): TByteArray;
const
  readBufSize = 1023;
var
  res: TByteArray;
  myFile: File of byte;
  readBuf: array [0..readBufSize] of byte;
  i, j: integer;
  readInFact: integer;
begin
  AssignFile(myFile, fileName);
  Reset(myFile);
  SetLength(res, FileSize(myFile));
  i := 0;
  repeat
    blockread(myFile, readBuf, readBufSize+1, readInFact);
    for j := 0 to readInFact - 1 do
    begin
      res[i] := readBuf[j];
      i := i + 1;
    end;
  until i >= FileSize(myFile);
  CloseFile(myFile);
  Result := res;
end;
```

А используем эту функцию вот так (здесь я передаю данные с клиента на сервер):

```
var
  test3: TByteArray;
....
test3 := FileReadAllBytes('bigfile.txt');
IdTCPClient1.WriteBuffer(Pointer(test3)^, Length(test3));
```

Ну а затем на сервере можно аналогично читать ReadBuffer и писать в файл (я делал сервер на C#, в нем уже есть функция WriteAllBytes) только сервер в данном случае должен знать размер файла в байтах, если не устраивает - то нужно перед байтами файла еще добавить в массив его размер, чтобы сервер сперва считал размер и знал сколько байт выделять под файл, при этом важно именно сразу сформировать массив байт и один раз вызвать WriteBuffer, иначе может перепутаться, сначала придет файл затем размер.

В общем, даже в такой старой Delphi все это с непривычки скорее нудно и долго, чем сложно.
А вот обеспечить стабильное персистентное соединение 24/7 без глюков при любых проблемах с интернетом, то есть качество на уровне скайпа и аськи, это реально сложно и я сам пока не решил.